# Example of a homeomorphism on the real line?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

I'm to give a short presentation on "basic topology" for a first semester undergrad analysis course. Naturally the professor does not expect me to master the topic, so I'm just trying to get some of the basic ideas.

I thought I might introduce the mug-doughnut example with a nice animated .gif, but I wanted to compare this idea to one-dimensional real analysis to tie into the course.

Is the appropriate example of a homeomorphism in the reals a continuous function from one compact set to another?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How about $f:(-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(t)=\tan(\pi/2 t)$? This example, to me, exemplifies how topological spaces are equivalent via homeomorphism if we can "stretch" one continuously to the other. This is a concrete example of the donut/mug example.

Comment: what do you mean "appropriate"? homeomorphism also need to be bijective, and don't necessarily need to be on compact sets. Think about 1/x

Comment: By "appropriate" I mean an example which is illustrative and also correct. Any function from  $$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$ which is bijective and continuous will be _correct_, yes?

Comment: Yes. This is not true in general, though.

Comment: Would it be interesting to show the stereographic projection that demonstrates that $\Bbb R$, plus a suitable point at infinity, is homeomorphic to a circle? If so I can write up the details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking. If $f$ is continuous and one-to-one from $R\to R$ then $f$ is a homeomorphism onto its image. A continuous image of a compact space is compact.

Comment: It is correct that such a continuous injection $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is a homeomorphism onto its image, but you need more argument than that this is true of compact Hausdorff spaces - $\Bbb R$ is not compact.